# How to persist URL hash fragments for SAML login?

Tags: redirect, authentication, single-page-application, saml

I am working on a single page application and is using SAML to authenticate user.

I am stuck with how to solve the following probelm

When an user tries to access some bookmarked URL

```
myapp.com/feature#some-part
```

the user will be redirected to SAML IDP's login page

```
some-idp.com/login
```

since the browser will keep track of the url fragment (#some-part)

the actual url the user sees is

```
some-idp.com/login#some-part
```

Now, the user will enter login credential and the browser will POST them to

```
some-idp.com/process-login
```

However, after done this, the browser will lose the url fragment and lose track of the original URL the user tries to go to.

My question is, how to preserve the url fragment across the SAML login process?

Comment: Is this only a problem when saving and using a bookmark or also when just pasting the link in the browser? What IDP are you using?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522580/url-fragment-lost-as-part-of-saml-token-authentication-workaround-standard-pa

Comment: *yes, if you properly urlencode the URL the fragment will be
preserved* https://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/Shibboleth-Idp-does-not-persist-URL-hash-fragments-across-a-login-redirect-tp7624686p7624736.html